# How to avoid sending e-mails that result in "Extra line breaks in this message were removed."

Tags: bash, email

I have a bash script that send an email like so ...

```
/bin/mailx -s "Unsatisfied dependencies report for the [$lc] YUM repo" red@example.com < /tmp/$prog.output
```

... when the email arrives to Outlook I get that stupid message about "Extra line breaks in this message were removed".  I tried running `unix2dos` on the `/tmp/$prog.output` file but that results in the report being sent as binary attachment.

Is there anything I can do from my bash script to prevent the annoying "extra line break in this message were removed" message?

Comment: Try Windows newlines: `\r\n`.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [outlook documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816)

"By default, the Auto Remove Line Breaks feature in Outlook is enabled. This causes the line breaks to be removed. Any two or more successive line breaks are not removed."

So maybe doubling up your new lines would avoid that.

Comment: Thanks that is better.  I added an `echo "" >> $prog.output` after every `echo` command.  It is not prefect though as the email is now double spaced. But it better that the "Extra line breaks ..." version of the email.

Comment: @RedCricket Sometimes you just have to pick the better of two evils (or disable the Auto Remove feature in Outlook...)

Answer (score 3):

In my situation I was able to use awk

echo "$variable" | awk '{ print $0"   " }' | mail -s ....

This reads every single line, and re-prints it with three spaces at the end. Outlook is now happy.

https://blog.dhampir.no/content/outlook-removes-extra-line-breaks-from-plain-text-emails-how-to-stop-it

Comment: `… |sed -e 's/$/ /'` works also well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, adding 3spaces (ou 2 tabs) at the end of all line works for a java library as well!